# How can I find exact elapsed time of a function in a binary executable?

Tags: timing, cpu-speed

For my research, I want to compare the exact run time of my program A and another program B. However, B source codes are not available for me. The program consists of some pre- and post- processing tasks which must be excluded from the run time.

**How can I measure only the time required for the main function (i.e., without pre and post processing functions)?**

The program is really fast and the run times (reported by the program itself) is almost lower than 1 second. (If I had the source code, I could put the main function within a loop to measure the elapsed time with more precision).
I think there may be some slow down functions (or emulators) to find the exact elapsed time, but I'm not sure if the method works.

**Any idea to measure the function is appreciated.**

(Platform: Fedora 17, That's likely the program is compiled with gcc with /O3 for optimization).

Comment: Use a profiler, e.g. [Zoom from RotateRight](http://www.rotateright.com/zoom) - they have a free 30 day evaluation license.

Comment: Can I use it even without the source code?

Comment: Yes of course - it will work best if compiled with `-g` but you should still get function names even if it doesn't have debug symbols. The only problem is when the executable has been completely stripped, but even then you should be able to identify the main function of interest in the timing profile. Anyway, go ahead and try it...